# Mean value theorem on Riemannian manifold?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Is there some generalisation of the classical mean value theorem for real-valued functions on an interval
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |\nabla f(c)||x-y|$$
for some $c$ between $(x,y)$ to the case where $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold? This MVT would involve the Riemannian gradient $\nabla_g$.

Comment: you can always restrict to paths from $x$ and $y$ and reduce to the classical case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If "between" means "$c$ lies on a minimizing geodesic from $x$ to $y$", the answer is yes.

Let $\gamma:[0, \ell] \to M$ be a *unit-speed* geodesic with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(\ell) = y$, and let $t_{0}$ be a point of $[0, \ell]$ at which the real-valued function $\left|g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr), \gamma'(t)\right)\right|$ achieves a maximum. Putting $c = \gamma(t_{0})$, we have
$$
\left|g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr), \gamma'(t)\right)\right|
  \leq \left|g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t_{0})\bigr), \gamma'(t_{0})\right)\right|
  \leq \left|\nabla f(c)\right|,\quad\text{for all $t$ in $[0, \ell]$,}
$$
and elementary calculus gives
\begin{align*}
\left|f(y) - f(x)\right|
  &= \left|\int_{0}^{\ell} g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr), \gamma'(t)\right)\, dt\right| \\
  &\leq \int_{0}^{\ell} \left|g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr), \gamma'(t)\right)\right|\, dt \\
  &\leq \int_{0}^{\ell} \left|g\left(\nabla f\bigl(\gamma(t_{0})\bigr), \gamma'(t_{0})\right)\right|\, dt \\
  &\leq \left|\nabla f(c)\right| \int_{0}^{\ell} dt \\
  &=  \left|\nabla f(c)\right|\, \left|x - y\right|.
\end{align*}
(The final equality uses the fact that $\gamma$ is minimizing. Clearly this hypothesis is crucial.)

Comment: The only thing that I dislike here is the fact that $c$ may coincide with $x$ or $y$. The mean value theorem for functions of a real variable gives $c$ in $(x,y)$, as requested by the OP. Also, the assumption of compactness of $M$ (made by the OP) is not necessary, as seen from the proof.