# Suppose $f$ is differentiable in $\overline{x}\in D$ then exists $M>0$ and $r>0$ such that...

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a open set and let $f:\,D\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{\text{m}}}$a function. Suppose $f$ is differentiable in $\overline{x}\in D$ then exists $M>0$ and $r>0$ such that
$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||}{||\overline{h}||}\leq M$
If $0<||\overline{h||}<r$

**My work:**

$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||}{||\overline{h}||}=\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})-df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})|}{||\overline{h}||}\leq\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}+\frac{||df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}$

> As $df_{x_{0}}$ is a linear transformation, then exists $M_{1}>0$ such that >$df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})\leq M_{1}$.

Moreover, $df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})\leq M_{1}\times||\overline{h}||$

Then exists $K_{1}>0$ such that

$\frac{||df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}<K_{1}$

for all $\overline{h}\in\mathbb{R^{\text{n}}}\,$if$||\overline{h}||\neq\overline{0}$

For hypothesis $f$ is differentiable in $\overline{x}$ then we have

$lim_{\overline{h}\rightarrow\overline{0}}\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}=0$

Then exists $K_{2}>0$ such that

$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}<K$

If $M=K_{1}+K_{2}$ then we have

$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||}{||\overline{h}||}=\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})-df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})|}{||\overline{h}||}\leq\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})|+df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}+\frac{||df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})||}{||\overline{h}||}=K_{1}+K_{2}=M$

In consequence:

$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||}{||\overline{h}||}<M$

**I have two problems with this proof**

> 1) That $r>0$ is for what? I can not understand its importance in this exercise... What happen if $||\overline{h||}>r$ ?
>
> 2) My teacher give me this hint. "As $df_{x_{0}}$ is a linear transformation, then exists $M_{1}>0$ such that >$df_{x_{0}}(\overline{h})\leq M_{1}$"
>
> Then, my question is. if $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation, always can i found a $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x)<M$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The $r>0$ means something locally, in general we don't have such nice thing $\dfrac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|}\leq M$ globally for $|h|$, which means that for large $|h|$ this inequality would fail.

2) Because you have restricted locally, and for bounded linear operator $T$, one has $|Tx|\leq M|x|$.

3) Not for all $x\in{\bf{R}}$, take for example $T(x)=x$, saying that $|T(x)|<M$ for all $x$ means that $|x|<M$ for $x\in{\bf{R}}$, this is clearly not true. As what has been said in 2), $|Tx|=|x|\leq M|x|$ is true, here $M=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The main step is to demonstrate the equivalent of **MVT in higher dimensions**, that is:

$||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||\leq||df_{x_{0}}\overline{h}||$

Since $df_{x_{0}}$ is a linear transformation (i.e. a matrix) then $\exists M$ s.t. $||df_{x_{0}}\overline{h}||\leq M||\overline{h}||$.

Thus, it follows immediately that:

$$\frac{||f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})||}{||\overline{h}||}\leq M$$

**NOTE**
I suppose that D should be assumed to be convex (i.e. path-connected).

**OTHER DISCUSSION on MVT**

[A generalization of the mean value theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704108/a-generalization-of-the-mean-value-theorem)