# Why "prove" the multi-value mean value theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

The the theorem says the sup-norm of the change in a value of a mapping due a displacement is less than or equal to the product of the sup-norm of the displacement and the maximum value of the norm of the derivative matrix.

That seems self evident.  The most by which the mapping could change would be if the largest component of displacement were the same component of the mapping with the greatest average rate of change.  The maximum possible value for that would be if its derivative of that component were constantly equal to the matrix norm of the derivative of the mapping.  Which is exactly what the theorem states.

Comment: Why prove anything then? Just put "self-evident" after everything and mathematics is solved forever.

Comment: Self-evident$\ne$true!!!

Comment: Think about the purpose of proving this as a reality check that our mathematical definitions really have the features we expect. It is "self-evident" that a continuous function is differentiable except at isolated points and that a convergent series of continuous functions is continuous because "why not?" Both of those properties of continuous functions are in fact false.

Comment: I have to confess, it is difficult to find concise words to explain why I believe this is self-evident.  It really relies on the definitions of the various norms involved, and what they actually imply.

Comment: @StevenHatton If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I saw the 'proof-explanation' tag. But it seems that this post is not really asking about the proof, is it?

Comment: @Jack I need to revisit this.  I will accept one of the answers for now.  My idea is that, a proper understanding of the norms involved will obviate the the need for the kind of proof given by Edwards.  But I've been too busy to work on it.  In particular, the matrix norm tells us the  largest magnitude of any component of any vertex in the image of the unit cube under the mapping provided by the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove also to verify under which hypothesis it is valid. In particular you need to assume that the domain of $f$ is path-connected.

[Suppose $f$ is differentiable in $\overline{x}\in D$ then exists $M>0$ and $r>0$ such that...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549639/suppose-f-is-differentiable-in-overlinex-in-d-then-exists-m0-and-r0/2549676#2549676)

[A generalization of the mean value theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704108/a-generalization-of-the-mean-value-theorem)

Answer (score 2):

Look at intermediate value theorem. The intermediate value theorem is maybe the most self evidently theorem there is, it is so self evidently that for years the mathematicians community didn't thought about proving it but just took it as a fact. **But** after years the mathematicians understood that just because looks logical in every way it doesn't mean it is true, the intermediate value theorem is not as simple to prove as how easy it look.

The problem with self evidently things is that our logic is lacking, and sometimes the truth is contradiction to what we are thinking is the truth, so if we won't prove all of the things we are using we can waste a lot of time with working with theorems that may be false.

You need to understand 1 thing about this:$$\boxed{\text{self evidently}\ne\text{a fact}}$$